# How can you mark a segment of memory as executable in C?

Tags: c, executable, jit

I am recently studying some JIT compiler. As far as I know, JIT is a technique to compile some scripting language code to native code on the fly (right before execution). As I imagined the internal of such a compiler, I figured out there must be a segment of dynamic-allocated buffer where the generated native code resides. But then we need a way to start running the code from within the buffer, which is holding data. I mean, you can't just put some code into a `char[]` and then jump into execution since the security implication, for which the OS must prevent you from doing so. There must be some way to mark the buffer as executable. Consider the following naive approach:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void *jit_some_native_code(void) {
  void *code_segment = malloc(1024);
  /*
   * bla bla bla...
   * Generate code into this code_segment.
   */

  return code_segment;
}

int main(void) {
  void *code = jit_some_native_code();
  /*
   * How can I start executing instruction in code?
   */

  typedef void (*func_ptr_t)(void);

  /*
   * This won't work. OS bans you doing so.
   */
  ((func_ptr_t)code)();

}
```

On Ubuntu the code will run but will exit with status code 26.
Given the type unsafe nature of C, the code can compile, but for C++, the compiler simply stops you. Does it means the JIT has to bypass compiler, along with setting the executable flag?

**Edit**: Besides `mprotect`, if you use `mmap`, you can also specify a permission to the page to map:

```
   PROT_EXEC  Pages may be executed.
   PROT_READ  Pages may be read.
   PROT_WRITE Pages may be written.
   PROT_NONE  Pages may not be accessed.
```

As such the page will have executable permission.

Comment: `((func_t) &code)` - you are executing the address of `code` pointer, not the function.... It should be `((func_t)code)()`. `for C++, the compiler simply stops you` ? Just cast `void *code = (void*)&some_jit_func` and you are ready to compile with C++.

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks for pointing out the error in the code. But I recall that C++ bans casting `void*` to function pointer?

Comment: Magically the `static_cast` bans such conversion while the C style cast permits it!

Comment: @ryyker the question is about how to mark a memory region executable, not how to properly call a function pointer. I believe my comment is not an answer.

Comment: A void* might not be large enough to hold a function pointer. Casting to a pointer of different size is undefined behavior. So, no, you can't just case void * to a function pointer. Neither in C nor C++. Why not declare `code = &some_jit_func` as the function pointer that it is? The jit-me-this-bit-of-script function should return a function pointer instead of void*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to make a region in the heap executable you can use [mprotect](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html).

```
int main() {
  typedef void (*func_t)(void);
  void *code = &some_jit_func;
  int pagesize = getpagesize();
  mprotect(code, pagesize,PROT_EXEC);
  ((func_t)code)();
}
```

You can also OR the flags with PROT_READ/PROT_WRITE

Comment: How does this _make_ the code executable?  Is _mprotect_ not simply marking a section of memory as protected?  (i.e. _because_ it is executable.)

Comment: The wording is a bit confusing but PROT_EXEC actually means allow that region to be executed. If you wanted no access to that region of memory at all, you would use PROT_NONE. If you wanted only read and write you would use PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE. By default the heap is not an executable region of memory.

Comment: @ryyker No. As clearly mentioned in its [manpage](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mprotect.html), `mprotect` _changes_ the access rights of a page of memory. In addition to that, most OSs will refuse to exec a page which is both executable and writable.

Comment: @Nina and mosvy - Thanks for clarifications!

Comment: @Nina From your answer I know that OS does provide such a way. But still somebody can put arbitrary stuff into the buffer and then call `mprotect` to gain execution permission. Isn't it open a security hole?

Comment: It is possible yes but it will be picked up by Host Intrusion Prevention Systems (HIPS) and will sometimes require elevation. On Windows, the variant is VirtualProtect but its easily picked up by Antiviruses and HIPS. People still do it but there are more discrete techniques. There are also other security measures to prevent someone just randomly inserting buffers like ASLR.

Comment: @cgsdfc: If they have the ability to call `mprotect`, they already have the ability to execute code. All `mprotect` does is extend that to executing dynamically generated code. The security concern only arises when someone finds a way (usually exploiting some other flaw in the program) to *both* populate a buffer with malicious code *and* convince the program to call `mprotect` on it. It doesn't actually provide any new privileges though; anything the program wasn't allowed to do, it can't do with the new code either; you need a privilege escalation as well to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are taking the address of an existing function. This will naturally point into a region of memory that is already executable. But that same region will not be writable on any modern system.

On the other hand if you malloc() some memory it will be writable but not executable. So any code you construct in your jit compiler will not be executable and trying to call a function you constructed there will fail. You have to make the memory executable first using [mprotect](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html).

For security reasons you should follow the `W^X` principle. Meaning that any page can only be writable or executable but never both. When you use mprotect to make the code executable also make it non-writable and vice versa. Never combine writable and executable.